# Empty directive fails on string

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have an object which contains a property called `route`, within the blade file I check if that property is empty:

```
@empty($chart->route)
    <script>
        alert('empty => ' + `{!! $chart->route !!}`)
    </script>
@else
    <script>
        alert('not empty')
    </script>
@endempty
```

The problem's that I get:

> empty => admin.test

which is of course wrong. Is this a bug or I missed something?

Comment: Looks like your empty() directive is not correct, can you share the code?  Alternatively you could try using

if(!empty($chart->route)

instead of empty(

Comment: @josezenem You can try to send a string to a view and use the `@empty` directive. In my case the content is `admin.test` but the directive fails to check.